# addcslashes(), charlist parameter - Why certain characters get converted?

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.3

```
addcslashes($str, $charlist)
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php

> "If charlist contains characters \n, \r etc., they are converted in
>   C-like style, while other non-alphanumeric characters with ASCII codes
>   lower than 32 and higher than 126 converted to octal representation."

1) So this would be \0, \a, \b, \f, \n, \r, \t, \v as far as the first part. What does C-like style conversion mean (any url that I could check on the Net), and why does the conversion take place?

2) Why the "other non-alphanumeric characters with ASCII codes lower than 32 and higher than 126" are converted to their octal representation?

Comment: 1) What is the C-like style conversion of these special characters. What they would be after the conversion? 2) As far as the ASCII ones (lower than 32 and higher than 126) - this would be like "157" (an octal sign for something, this exists) and a slash in front of this? I just dont understand this part in the explanation. Why does the conversion take place?

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
echo addcslashes("abc\nfoo\1bar", "\n\1")
```

the output is:

```
abc\nfoo\001bar
```

The purpose is to return the string in the format that C and PHP programmers are likely to write the literal. We usually write `\n` rather than `\012` for newline, `\e` rather than `\033` for Escape, `\r` rather than `\015` for carriage return, etc, so that's what's returned. But most other non-printing characters don't have short escape sequences, so they're returned with octal escapes.